# Node.js strApi connect to Google Cloud

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, strapi

I have a api that i can run perfectly local on my local machine. It uses msql here is what i have done:

Local:

./enviroments/development/database.json

```
{
    "defaultConnection": "default",
    "connections": {
        "default": {
            "connector": "strapi-hook-bookshelf",
            "settings": {
                "client": "mysql",
                "host": "127.0.0.1",
                "srv": false,
                "port": 3306,
                "database": "[REDACTED]",
                "username": "[REDACTED]",
                "password": "[REDACTED]"
            },
            "options": {
                "ssl": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

./enviroments/development/server.json

```
{
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 1337,
  "proxy": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "autoReload": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "cron": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "admin": {
    "autoOpen": true
  }
}
```

Then i started MAMP up and did an import of the database in phpmyadmin.
Perfect everything works.

Now i would like to make it live. So i am using Google Cloud.
I have create a msql instance on google cloud platform
I have created a database "test"

My question is what should my database.json look like now?

I have tried

```
    {
        "defaultConnection": "default",
        "connections": {
            "default": {
                "connector": "REDACTED",
                "settings": {
                    "client": "mysql",
                    "host": "Public IP address i found on googleCloud platform",
have also tried /cloudsql/[REDACTED]

i have tried to put in
"socketPath": "/cloudsql/${process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}"


                    "srv": false,
                    "port": 3306,
// dont know what the port should be
                    "database": "test",
                    "username": "REDACTED",
                    "password": "REDACTED"
                },
                "options": {
                    "ssl": false
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried setting up a app.yaml file.
The closes i got it to working was when i deployed it it said server err 500.
In all the other cases it just fails.

Can anyone please help me with the correct setup as i dont know what im doing
Want to learn how to do this and i have spent all day already :( and got nowhere

I have now tried this. This is my app.staging.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs10
service: strapi

env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: staging
  MYSQL_USERNAME: REDACTED
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: REDACTED
  MYSQL_DATABASE: test
  INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: REDACTED"
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: "REDACTED"
```

And my config/staging/databse.json looks like this

```
{
    "defaultConnection": "default",
    "connections": {
        "default": {
            "connector": "strapi-hook-bookshelf",
            "settings": {
                "client": "mysql",
                "host": "${process.env.MYSQL_HOST || '127.0.0.1'}",
                "port": "${process.env.MYSQL_PORT || '3306'}",
                "database": "${process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE}",
                "username": "${process.env.MYSQL_USERNAME}",
                "password": "${process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD}",
                "socketPath": "/cloudsql/${process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}"
            },
            "options": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Deployed but when i visit the link it says

Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

Comment: Is the application trying to connect to Cloud SQL for MySQL outside of Google Cloud? The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app) that was posted in the answer below should help you with it. Otherwise, if your application is hosted on Google Cloud, please specify which Google Cloud service you're trying to connect to Cloud SQL from.

Answer (score 0):

"NodeJS" could be anything, as `INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME` [App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard).

You probably have to [create a user](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-manage-users#creating) and configure access.

See [Connecting from an external application using the proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#proxy).